# Using 7" TouchScreen Cape on Beaglebone Black

Tags: node.js, debian, beagleboneblack

So, im developing an robotics application that uses a BeagleboneBlack as a controller for 3 different servos.

I know how to access the pins and everything from Cloud9 IDE directly into the board.

However, im using a  7" cape ( 4d Systems, 4DCAPE-70T ) and when i connect them, Debian automatically starts up.

I guess my question is, how do you code an app with a UI that can be accessed from the Debian distro directly from the 7" screen?

All my research has lead me to a final decision, which is mounting a node.js server on the bbb and making an HTML interface and with the bonescript libs, access the pins.

Has anybody done anything similar to this?

If anybody has a another approach to this, that would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If any time traveller out there stumbles upon this question, here is how i figured it out:

1) Get rid of bonescript. It will give you a hard time assigning pins for PWM and some other uses. Instead, use octalbonescript. [reference to repo](https://github.com/theoctal/octalbonescript)

2) Install socket.io

try and start a local server with it. Follow various tutos out there. If you run into a boot-up error regarding the server, use port 8090.

3) Design a web page that connects to a local host ( beaglebone itself) using socket.io. Again, various tutos out there.

DONT TOUCH THE KERNEL, NOR THE FILE TREE. Its unnecesary.

4) Open that same web page on your beaglebone. That way, you dont need an internet connection or whatever. The javascript side of the web page will call the appropriate methods on the beaglebone through socket.io ( socket.emit() ).

- Its important to understand that all the beaglebone-side instructions, such as pin access, pwm and such, are performed on the same file where the socket is made. The web page 'calls' this methods on the bbb.

5) Enjoy!

I was using it for a robotics project. We were building a delta robot controlled by the Beaglebone Black ( Rev C ). I am serious, start with what i am telling you, you will save a LOT of time.

Edit: Guess i forgot the most important part. The cape uses several of the pins, incluiding various PWM. Octalbonescript, as of this moment, does not support capes. It will, but not at the moment. So, dump the screen and use an ethernet cable to connect your beaglebone to the network. That way, you can access the interface from any device through a browser at beaglebone:8090. ( NOT beaglebone.local:8090 )